# How to convert from vertex_color to material and export FBX file

Tags: materials, color

I have some problem with my blender code export to fbx file. I set color by vertex_color and set mode is Vertex_paint. But when I export this object to fbx file and open in Unity it is not include color. I think the reason might be dont set color for material of object. So could you help me to convert ?
This is my code. Thank you so much for your help

```
import math

# mesh arrays
verts = []
faces = []

# mesh variables
numX = 10
numY = 10

# wave variables
freq = 1
amp = 1
scale = 1

#fill verts array
for i in range (0, numX):
    for j in range(0,numY):
        x = scale * i
        y = scale * j
        z = scale*((amp*math.cos(i*freq))+(amp*math.sin(j*freq)))
        vert = (x,y,z) 
        verts.append(vert)

#fill faces array
count = 0
for i in range (0, numY *(numX-1)):
    if count < numY-1:
        A = i
        B = i+1
        C = (i+numY)+1
        D = (i+numY)
        face = (A,B,C,D)
        faces.append(face)
        count = count + 1
    else:
        count = 0

#create mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("wave")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("wave",mesh)
#set mesh location
object.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)

#create mesh from python data
mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)

vert_list = mesh.vertices
color_map_collection = mesh.vertex_colors
if len(color_map_collection) == 0:
    color_map_collection.new()
else:
    color_map_collection.active

color_map = color_map_collection['Col']
i = 0

for poly in mesh.polygons:
    for idx in poly.loop_indices:
        loop = mesh.loops[idx]
        v = loop.vertex_index
        final = (0.1,0.5,0.2,1)
        color_map.data[i].color = final     
        i += 1

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT', toggle=False)
```

Comment: Do the colors look like you'd expect in blender?
Unity doesn't read vertex color by default, you have to enable it. Also when you build, you need to enable vertex color under the mesh optmization options. 
Other than that I never had troubles with vertex color and fbx.

Comment: HI @FrederikSteinmetz absolutely, I would like to make the color look like blender in Unity. Thank you for your reply. Btw if you have any document or example about how to enable vertex color under the mesh optimization options in blender/ even Unity, please share for me. Honestly, I pretty fresh in this field. Thank you

Comment: before I do this, do you have a shader that handles vert. col. in Unity?

Comment: Your mean is vertex and faces define? Sorry for my silly question. Because I am not clearly understand "shader".

Comment: You won't see any vertex colors in Unity, unless you have a shader (material) that can read them.

Comment: Actually, this is my matter, my code just work with vertex colors and I dont know how to add vertex colors into material ( sorry if something wrong). So I run within above code and in VERTEX PAINT mode I can see color perfectly. But when I export it to FBX and import those FBX file into Unity, the color can not appearance.

Comment: How are you checking if the colors get imported in Unity? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: So I just import it into Unity and my expectation is look the object with full color. But I can not. I just read FBX file in Unity without any set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity is a game engine, not a vertex editing engine. While you can build or download tools to edit meshes inside of Unity, I'd advise you to stick to Blender for that. Unity displays everything similar to Eevee. If you assign a default material to an object in Eevee it also won't show vertex colors, unless you tell your material to read them. In Blender, you need a built-in node for that, in Unity you need a shader that can read and display them.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/finding-and-using-a-vertex-colors-shader.236366/
Unity will also omit any vertex color information in the build, unless you tell it to keep them.
[image]
This option is in the Player Settings.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I actually import fbx within color into Unity

Comment: if it helped yout, would you mind accepting my answer?